# How do I make a turtle object go behind another turtle object in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to be able to easily make a square go behind a group of lines without lagging the program or causing any major bugs. I wanted to do all of this using the turtle module as I am currently making a game using that module. I have attempted this several times, but it was never working the way I wanted it to. I'm also using Python 3.8.

Here is my attempt at this problem I've been having:

```
import turtle
#The Setup
wn = turtle.Screen()
global WIDTH
global HEIGHT
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 650
wn.setup(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
turtle.speed(0)
wn.title("Game by iAmInfernal")
wn.bgcolor('white')
wn.tracer(0)
#I create a turtle object
t = turtle. Turtle()
#I create a player object
player = turtle.Turtle()
t.stamp()
down = 0
player.shape('square')
player.color('red')
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.stamp()
#I make a function that will make 150 lines with a space of 10 units
def makeLines():
    global down
    for item in range(150):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(-400, 300 - down)
        t.stamp()
        t.pendown()
        t.hideturtle()
        t.pensize(3)
        t.forward(800)
        down += 10




while True:
    makeLines()
    wn.update()
```

If you execute this snippet of code you will be able to see that there are many lines with a red square in the center. However as many times I tried, the red square never went behind those group of lines. How exactly do I make the red square go behind those group of lines?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Turtles can't appear *behind* the things they draw, whether via *drawing* or *stamping*.  However, turtles *can* appear behind other turtles, so one workaround might be to make the lines themselves be turtles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 650
SPACING = 10

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def makeLines():
    down = 0

    for _ in range(HEIGHT // SPACING):
        turtle = prototype.clone()
        turtle.sety(HEIGHT/2 - down)
        turtle.showturtle()

        down += SPACING

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(0)

player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.color('red')
player.penup()
player.stamp()

prototype = Turtle()
prototype.hideturtle()
prototype.shape('square')
prototype.shapesize(2 / CURSOR_SIZE, WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE, 1)
prototype.penup()

makeLines()
screen.update()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

The problem then becomes controlling the layering of turtles where the basic rule of thumb is "the last thing that moved is on top".